# Wrong select tag rendered id - asp-for property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Here is my code behind

```
namespace Cinema.WebCore.Pages.MovieDateHall
{
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly Cinema.WebCore.Data.CinemaContext _context;

    public CreateModel(Cinema.WebCore.Data.CinemaContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public SelectList Movies { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        MovieDateHallSeats movieDateHall = new MovieDateHallSeats();
        movieDateHall.Movies = _context.Movies.ToList();

        Movies = new SelectList(movieDateHall.Movies, "Id", "MovieTitle");

        return Page();
    }

}
}
```

and front-end code is

```
@page

@model Cinema.WebCore.Pages.MovieDateHall.CreateModel

<select asp-for="Movies" asp-items="Model.Movies">
   <option value="">Pick one</option>
</select>
```

It works but the rendered output for the select tag has `multiple=multiple` which is not I need.

`<select id="Movies" multiple="multiple" name="Movies">
       <option value="">Pick one</option>
       <option value="1">Matrix</option>
   </select>`

What I need is ...

`<select id="MovieId" name="Movies">
       <option value="">Pick one</option>
       <option value="1">Matrix</option>
   </select>`

Is my binding at the code-behind incorrect?

```
[BindProperty]
public SelectList Movies { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have another property

```
   public string SelectedMovie {get;set;}
```

And use it for the asp-for

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `select` in a wrong way. For `asp-for` you should put your property handles selected value

```
<select asp-for="MovieId" asp-items="Model.Movies">
   <option value="">Pick one</option>
</select>
```

Example:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

///

```
form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Home"  asp-antiforgery="true">
    <div>
        <div>
            <label asp-for="Name"></label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="Name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label asp-for="Price"></label>
            <input asp-for="Price" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label asp-for="CompanyId"></label>
            <select asp-for="CompanyId" asp-items="ViewBag.Companies"></select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```